# standard_init_linux.go:211:exec user process caused "no such file or directory" with alpine linux and python

Tags: python, docker, alpine-linux, dockerpy

I have a directory which contains the docker file, a attack.py and a requirements.txt.

Using that, I created the following dockerfile:

```
FROM arm64v8/python:3.7-alpine

COPY qemu-arm-static /usr/bin

COPY ./ app-ids
WORKDIR /app-ids

RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

CMD["python","./attack.py"]
```

However, the pip install line throws:
standard_init_linux.go:211:exec user process caused "no such file or directory"

I can't figure out why. Using commands like ls, pwd and so on in an attempt to debug this yields the same error.

Can anyone explain what exactly I am doing wrong?

Comment: This yields the exact same error.

Comment: then check @linpy comment.

Comment: That does not seem to be the issue too. I fixed this but the error remains.

Comment: are you behind any proxy?

Comment: Not that I know of. Is there any possibility to check if that is a network issue?

Comment: yes you can check ```RUN ping -q -w1 -c1 google.com &>/dev/null && echo online || echo offline```

Comment: See the edit. With your edited ping command the same error gets thrown so something doesnt add up there...

Comment: try to run dos2unix on all of the files in your host directoy which containe the docker files

Comment: That didn't help either but good idea.

Comment: Your error message and Dockerfile do not match.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I guess you are trying to build the docker image on a non-arm64v8 platform. I would assume that for the rest of the answer.

The solution provided will be specific for Ubuntu distribution (host), but I guess it should be similar on other linux distribution.

**SOLUTION 1** [working on Ubuntu 18.04]

From https://github.com/docker/for-linux/issues/56 we can see that there is bug currently in the packages for Debian (and thus Ubuntu?).

```
sudo apt-get install qemu-user-static

git clone https://github.com/computermouth/qemu-static-conf.git
sudo mkdir -p /lib/binfmt.d
sudo cp qemu-static-conf/*.conf /lib/binfmt.d/
sudo systemctl restart systemd-binfmt.service
```

This will remove the `qemu-user-binfmt` method from solution 2. However in that package the provided configuration files are not in the folder, and missconfigured, to be used by `systemd-binfmt`.

Also, we get the configuration files from a git repository and place them in a folder where the systemd-binfmt looks into: `/lib/binfmt.d/` (not `/var/lib/binfmts/` as install by qemu-user-static)

Then check the status:

```
systemctl status systemd-binfmt
```

And try to compile your docker again. It should work!

**SOLUTION 2** [not currently working on Ubuntu 18.04]

It used to be a manually configuration process on previous, but now it is supported via a apt package:

```
sudo apt-get install qemu-user-binfmt
```

With that it will create the `binfmt` configuration for all platforms under `/proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc/qemu-*`. And when your system detects that the executable is for arm, it will call qemu instead of trying to execute directly.

Here is a link to a more detailed explanation: https://ownyourbits.com/2018/06/13/transparently-running-binaries-from-any-architecture-in-linux-with-qemu-and-binfmt_misc/ or https://ownyourbits.com/2018/06/27/running-and-building-arm-docker-containers-in-x86/

To understand how it works, it is good to the following paragraph:

> The kernel recognizes the ARM ELF magic, and uses the interpreter
>   `/usr/bin/qemu-arm-static` , which is the correct QEMU binary for the
>   architecture.  0x7F 'ELF'  in hexadecimal is `7f 45 4c 46`, so we can
>   see how the magic and the mask work together, considering the
>   structure of the ELF header

```
typedef struct {
    unsigned char e_ident[EI_NIDENT];   /* 0x7F 'ELF' four byte ELF magic for any architecture */
    uint16_t e_type;
    uint16_t e_machine;                 /* architecture code, 40=0x28 in the case of ARM */
    uint32_t e_version;
    ElfN_Addr e_entry;
    ElfN_Off e_phoff;
    ElfN_Off e_shoff;
    uint32_t e_flags;
    uint16_t e_ehsize;
    uint16_t e_phentsize;
    uint16_t e_phnum;
    uint16_t e_shentsize;
    uint16_t e_shnum;
    uint16_t e_shstrndx;
} ElfN_Ehdr;
```

Note that the `binfmt` configuration is shared by docker, therefore it will trying to get the `/usr/bin/qemu-arm-static` inside the container. And that is the reason you still need to copy the /usr/bin/qemu-arm-static.