# /bin/sh returning non zero code : 1 in docker alpine

Tags: docker, dockerfile, qemu, alpine-linux

I have the following dockerfile:

```
FROM arm64v8/python:3.8-alpine
ADD ./src /app
WORKDIR /app
#RUN pip install  --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt
RUN apk update && apk add bash
CMD ["/usr/local/bin/python","attack.py"]
```

However, when I try to build this using

```
sudo docker build --platform linux/arm32v6 -f docker/Dockerfile -t test .
```

I get the following error as soon as I try to run pip install or apk update:
[image]

I commented out both of these lines and tried to debug it using

```
docker run -it test /bin/ash
```

as well as usr/bin/ash; usr/bin/sh; /bin/sh and so on
Any of these fails with the error above.

Why? I'd be really thankful for any help.

Comment: Thank you. However I can't access the shell either. Why?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58972541/standard-init-linux-go211exec-user-process-caused-no-such-file-or-directory?noredirect=1#comment104199080_58972541

Comment: @CharlesDuffy No, same error.

Comment: I added that since you do not need to ask the same question more than once, maybe you need to try to set a bounty on your old question

Comment: @LinPy it doesnt, that is a different problem

Comment: Also, silly question, but is your host really an arm64v8 platform? If you're running binaries from an incompatible architecture, of course everything will fall. (This happening with a fairy obscure image also makes it hard for us out here to test/verify that the image genuinely works).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy my host is an x86 machine but I use qemu and copied the static packages to /usr/bin on the docker image

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I forgot to copy the qemu-arm-static packages to the docker container.
Now after I did that, I get the error "exec user process caused "permission denied"", so a different error at least.

Comment: @DanielSiegel How could I regenerate the error? I tried this & it worked perfectly for me-

```
FROM arm64v8/python:3.8-alpine
RUN apk update && apk add bash
```

Comment: @AdityaMishra I don't know. The permissions problem mentioned above seems to persist but is not deterministic. What host machine and OS did you use?

Comment: @DanielSiegel I am using macos & x86 architecture. But I don't understand what are you trying to achieve here? Could you share the app code or something?

Answer (score 0):

If you look into your base image [arm64v8/python:3.8-alpine](https://github.com/docker-library/python/blob/0b1fb9529c79ea85b8c80ff3dd85a32a935b0346/3.8/alpine3.10/Dockerfile) it removes everything at the end of docker build, everything mean `APK` as well, so that is why your command failing, and also there is no `bash` in the base image so you will not able to run the container with bash.

you can consider this image as a scratch there is only `python3`.

Answer (score 0):

The "no such file or directory" is going to be from the kernel looking for your qemu static binaries. You should configure qemu static binaries with the `--fix-binary` option which will result in the `F` flag in `/proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc` files. This is needed to support binfmt when running in a chroot or mount namespace environment. In most distributions these days, that involves installing a new version of the binfmt_misc static binaries.

More details are available in https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v4.12/admin-guide/binfmt-misc.html

The Debian bug is here: https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=868030

And similar Ubuntu issue: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/qemu/+bug/1815100