# Alpine Python image throw exec user process caused "no such file or directory" where Raspian/Debian works

Tags: python, docker, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3, alpine-linux

A simple Dockerfile that executes a shell script as entrypoint like this

```
FROM python:3
WORKDIR /app

COPY . .
RUN chmod +x entrypoint.sh
CMD ["python", "/app/src/api.py"]
ENTRYPOINT ["./entrypoint.sh"]
```

works: `entrypoint.sh` is called, which itself executes `python /app/src/api.py` on a RPI 3.

`entrypoint.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash
echo starting entrypoint
set -x
exec "$@"
```

Since I don't need anything Debian/Raspbian specific, I'd like to use the alpine image to reduce image size. So I changed `FROM python:3` to `FROM python:3-alpine` without any further changes.

But now the container doesn't start:

```
api_1      | standard_init_linux.go:211: exec user process caused "no such file or directory"
test_api_1 exited with code 1
```

Why doesn't this work on Alpine? I don't see any problem since `/app/entrypoint.sh` exists and it's also executable:

```
Step 5/7 : RUN ls -lh
 ---> Running in d517a83c5b9b
total 12K    
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root          54 Jul 11 18:35 entrypoint.sh
drwxr-xr-x    2 root     root        4.0K Jul 11 18:48 src
```

In a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58972541/standard-init-linux-go211exec-user-process-caused-no-such-file-or-directory), the image was buld on a non-arm system. This is not the case for me, I'm building directly on the RPI.

Not sure if this is Raspbian or Alpine related. I also tried using the absolute path `ENTRYPOINT ["/app/entrypoint.sh"]`: Still working on `python:3` image, but broken in `python:3-alpine`.

Answer (score 2):

The problem was that my entrypoint uses bash as shebang without thinking about it:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo starting entrypoint
set -x
exec "$@"
```

But alpine doesn't include GNU Bash, which is installed on Debian/Raspbian by default. The *no such file or directory* was specified to the interpreter from the shebang, not the entrypoint script itself.

Since my script is not indent to make something that requires bash features, I just changed `#!/bin/bash` to `#!/bin/sh` and it could be also started on the alpine image.

Comment: If you answer your own question, you could at least put the information need to identity the error (the shebang) into the question.

Comment: @KlausD. Thank you for the suggestion, I added the entrypoint script in the question, too,